# Dropping a pin in Android Map

Tags: android, google-maps, location

Good morning,

I've searched in Google and here in StackOverFlow, and I'm still unable to find a way in which I can display a Map in my Android App, I don't care if we don't use Google Maps, I just need a way for users to drop a pin anywhere in the map and get the coordinates.

I'd really appreciate if someone could put me in track.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

http://youtu.be/3WgI8cHCH2o?list=PLshdtb5UWjSqgZ1yaeyKMiLyY4x1egK3c

this would help you clear and crisp beginners tutorial

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this a long time ago, it just requires some doc checking.